# When returning to a page, set the drop down option to last picked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have an asp.net vb website I'm building in vs 2010. It has two tabs, one with a gridview that is filterable with a dropdown.
I want to be able to, when returning to the gridview tab, set the dropdown to the last chosen option.
So when a user leaves the gridview tab to work in the other tab, when they return, it'll be set to the item they had selected when they clicked out.

How do I go about this while working around the fact that page_load comes before selectedIndexChanges

Comment: Would be helpful if you can add your code here

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching this from the wrong angle.Switching between tabs shouldn't cause a post back in the first place.You can very easily implement a tab control using Twitter Bootstrap:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div id="content">
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tabOne" data-toggle="tab">Tab One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabTwo" data-toggle="tab">Tab Two</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabOne">
            <h1>Put the GridView and the drop down here</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tabTwo">
            <h1>Tab number two controls go here...</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If going to another tab causes a postback, try putting the tabs inside an UpdatePanel so that the page doesn't refresh.

Otherwise, try adding the dropdown value to a session i.e. `Session(MyValue") = dropdownlist.selectedvalue` and then on Page Load have the dropdownlist.selectedvalue be equal to Session("MyValue)"